# Convex cost functions and Fisher consistency

Tags: classification, consistency

In Section 4.2 of the paper by [Boucheron et al.](http://www.econ.upf.edu/~lugosi/esaimsurvey.pdf), the authors argue that the minimizer $f^*$ of the cost functional 
$$A(f) = \mathbb{E}\{\phi(-Yf(X))\}$$
is such that the classifier $g^*$, constructed from $f^*$ by
$$ g^*(x) =
  \begin{cases}
   1 & \text{if } f^*(x)\geq 0 \\
   -1       & \text{otherwise}
  \end{cases}$$
is the Bayes classifier. Note that the cost function $\phi$ is a non-negative, strictly convex, and non-decreasing function.

In order to prove the claim, the authors argue that $\phi'$ is strictly increasing. Where is that coming from?

Comment: Quick reminder from Wikipedia,
_"A loss function is Fisher consistent if the population minimizer of the risk leads to the Bayes optimal decision rule."_

Comment: (This should be a comment to the reply but there are so many comments there it would be lost in the noise!) Note that $\phi$ is *not* assumed to have a second derivative.  The conclusion follows from the assumptions that $\phi$ is *nondecreasing* and *strictly* convex. Proof: If $\phi'$ were not strictly increasing on a nontrivial interval $[a,b]$, then $\phi'$ would be constant on some nontrivial subinterval $[a_0,b_0]$, implying $\phi$ would not be strictly convex on $[a_0,b_0]$, contradicting the assumptions, QED.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Given that $\phi$ is twice differentiable, [strictly convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_function#Strongly_convex_functions) and nondecreasing, you have that $\phi^{\prime\prime}(x)>0$ for all $x$ in the interior of its domain. This implies that $\phi^{\prime}(x)$ is strictly increasing (given that its derivative is positive).

Comment: Even when the second derivative of $f$ exists everywhere, the first sentence of this answer is not true. Take $f(x) = x^{2n}$ with $n \geq 2$.

Comment: @cardinal that function is not "nondecreasing".

Comment: That depends on its domain of definition.

Comment: @cardinal Choose one :)

Comment: $[0,\infty) {}$.

Comment: @cardinal then it is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: Sure it is. ${ }$

Comment: @cardinal ???? Right derivate?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3512/discussion-between-cardinal-and-procrastinator)

Comment: (+1) I hope you don't mind the typo correction and small tweak. :)

Comment: @cardinal No problem, I actually appreciate this interesting discussion.

Comment: @Procrastinator cardinal is right.  Derivative of X$^2n$ is 2n X$^2n-1$ which is 0 at x=0.  It is an inflection point on the curve. If 2n is replaced by n and n is odd then it is a local minimum at x=0.

Comment: I am still not used to Latex! I meant X$^2^n$ and X$2$n$-$1$ above.

Comment: Still don't have it right sorry.  I think you know what I mean.

Comment: Do you mean the derivative of $X^{2n}$ is $2nX^{2n-1}$? $\LaTeX$ code for that is `$X^{2n}$` and `$2nX^{2n-1}$`